How do i configure right the staging and temp buckets at DataprocCreateClusterOperator?
I'm trying to find how to set the temp and staging buckets at the DataprocOperator. I've searched for all the internet and didnt find a good awnser.
import pendulum
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocCreateClusterOperator, \
    DataprocDeleteClusterOperator, DataprocSubmitJobOperator
from airflow.decorators import task, dag

# config = Variable.get("teste", deserialize_json=True)
config = {
    "cluster_name": 'teste',
    "region": 'us-central1',
    "project_id": 'test-dataproc'
}

default_args = {
    "owner": "Airflow",
    "start_date": pendulum.datetime(2024, 4, 26, tz="America/Sao_Paulo"),
    "retries": 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=3)
}

@dag(
    "teste_dataproc",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 3 * * 1-5',
    params=config,
    catchup=False,
    tags=["TESTE"],
)
def teste_dataproc():

    CLUSTER_CONFIG = {
        "gce_cluster_config" : {
            "zone_uri": "us-central1-a",
            "internal_ip_only": False,
        },
        "master_config": {
            "num_instances": 1,
            "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-2",
            "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 25},
        },
        "worker_config": {
            "num_instances": 2,
            "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-2",
            "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 25},
        },
        "software_config": {
            "properties": {
                "spark:spark.executor.memory": "3g",  # Memory for each executor
                "spark:spark.executor.cores": "2",    # Number of cores per executor
                "spark:spark.executor.instances": "4"  # Number of executor instances
            }
        }
    }

    create_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
        task_id="create_dataproc_cluster",
        project_id="{{ params.project_id }}",
        cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
        region="{{ params.region }}",
        cluster_name="{{ params.cluster_name }}",
        staging_bucket="gs://teste/dataproc/staging",  # Staging bucket
        temp_bucket="gs://teste/dataproc/temp"  # Temp bucket
    )

    create_cluster

teste_dataproc()

I know that the staging_bucket and the temp_bucket params are not correct, so, if someone knows something, would be a good help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
